# How to set up a Cron job?

Tags: cron, invoice

I am trying to set up Recurring Invoices as documented on http://www.fusioninvoice.com/support/recurring-invoices but I don't understand and cant work out what to do.

I have found a alphanumeric 'key' but not sure where or what to do?

Do I need to createa file or something?

Answer (score 2):

If curl is available on your system, you can schedule it to ping the URL.
Use crontab -e to edit the cron table and create a new entry. For example, this will ping the URL every day at midnight.

```
0 0 * * *  /usr/bin/curl --silent http://your-server.com/index.php/invoices/cron/recur/your-cron-key-here &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Perfect answer!  Was looking for the same thing - this worked a charm!