# Run cronjob https php script with parameters

Tags: php, https, cron

So I have php script, and want to run in with cron tab (unix)

php script url:

```
https://www.domain.com/admin/index.php?route=do&key=54asd55asd
```

How can add it to crontab?

I tried

```
* * * * * lynx -dump https://www.domain.com/admin/index.php?route=do&key=54asd55asd
* * * * * wget https://www.domain.com/admin/index.php?route=do&key=54asd55asd
```

but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem lies in the `&` that don't go through. What if you quote the URL --> `wget "https://..."`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a cli browser, use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) instead, with which you will be able to send POST parameters as well if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The are a few options here, depending on GET/POST request:

GET Request:

`* * * * * * /usr/bin/GET http://www.example.com?foo=1 >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1 >/dev/null 2>&1`

Or POST:

`* * * * * * /usr/bin/curl --data "foo=1" http://www.example.com/file.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

I would look into the [cURL Manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

Could also write a php file to `curl` the site for you, then add that to your crontab.  For instance: [How would I use a cron job to send an HTML GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558041/how-would-i-use-a-cron-job-to-send-an-html-get-request).
Then handling of errors and whatnot could be dealt with locally.